# Is it possible to create this context-free grammatic?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Is it possible to create this grammatic?
$$
\left. 0^i 1^j 2^k \right| i + j \ne 2k 
$$

I try to create this, but I don't understand. I assume that we have to output $k$ characters '2' beforehand. But I think I'm confused. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are confused about. Do you understand what are typical elements in your grammar?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I've done similar grammatic before, but when i + j = 2k. But making this grammatic is much harder for me.

Comment: I don't understand what "making a grammatic" means in this context. Are you talking about designing an automaton to accept this context free grammar?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry, I'm not a native speaker and it can be problematic to get my message right way.

Comment: So if you made the $i+j=2k$ one, why not just negate it?

Comment: @gt6989b The complement of a context-free language is not necessarily context-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S\rightarrow A$

$A\rightarrow 0A2 | B$

$B\rightarrow 1B2 | C$

$C\rightarrow C2 | 2$

This should produce the language $0^i1^j2^k$ with $i+j<k$.

$S\rightarrow A | E$

$A\rightarrow 0A2 | B$

$B\rightarrow 0B | 0C$

$C\rightarrow 1C | \epsilon$

$E\rightarrow 0E2 | F$

$F\rightarrow 1F2 | 2G$

$G\rightarrow 2G | \epsilon$

This should produce the language $0^i1^j2^k$ with $i+j>k$.

Now you can take the union. With a similar idea you should be able to do with $2k$ instead of $k$.